# Tmux not responding to bind-key

Tags: tmux

I have this in my `.tmux.conf`:

```
bind-key -n M-1 select-window -t :1
bind-key -n M-2 select-window -t :2
bind-key -n M-h select-window -p
bind-key -n M-l select-window -n
```

I'm expecting alt+h to go to the prev window and alt+l to advance to the next. alt+1 and alt+2 work as expected. If I change M to C, then ctrl+h/ctrl+l work fine. ctrl+l even overrides zsh's key binding which would be to clear the shell. If I pull up the tmux command prompt and put in :select-window -p (or -n), it works fine.

How can I figure out why these key bindings aren't working?

Edit: `tmux list-keys` also doesn't show M-h or M-l as having been bound to anything else.

Comment: (1) "and h to advance to the next" – Why? Your code states `M-l`. (2) Your settings work for me in KDE+`konsole`. First there's the kernel, then my display server with my desktop environment, then my terminal emulator, line discipline, only then tmux, another line discipline, finally the shell. Even if I got the details wrong, the general rule is that any earlier program in this chain may intercept a keystroke before it gets to a later program. Check the bindings in your desktop environment and in your terminal emulator, maybe one of them interferes.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski that was a typo, fixed. As for DE/etc, I'm running this in Kitty on macOS. I've checked my macOS keyboard shortcuts to make sure alt+h and alt+l aren't bound to anything and I didn't find anything.

Comment: In a shell *outside of tmux* type Ctrl+v, Alt+1. What do you see? Is it `^[1`? Now type Ctrl+v, Alt+h. What do you see?

Comment: ctrl+v, alt+1: `^[1`, ctrl+v, alt+h shows nothing, but if I then hit `return`, then `^M` shows up.

Comment: This means that Alt+h did not get to the shell. Similarly it would not get to tmux if tmux was there. So either it was not generated by your keyboard at all (unlikely) or something in the chain mentioned earlier interfered.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski yet, from within tmux (and without) if I run `skhd -o`, it recognizes my alt and h/l keypresses.

Comment: I don't know this tool. Does it read "keys" from its stdin or from its controlling terminal? Unlikely. I found that "skhd is a simple hotkey daemon for macOS", so it probably bypasses any terminal emulator and line discipline (like e.g. `xev` in X in Linux). At least now we know your keyboard sends something upon Alt+h. What if you try with a terminal emulator other than kitty?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski from Terminal.app, outside tmux:


ctrl+v, alt+1: `¡`
ctrl+v, alt+h: <nothing>
ctrl+v, alt+h, return: `^M`